# Post being scheduled that shouldnt be schedulded

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

Theres something strange in the neighborhood.. Seriously.. I think my wordpress is haunted. I've been working on a plugin that creates a post from a form and its been working fine for several weeks, submit the form, the post is published.

Now, bear in mind that Ive made no changes to the function that creates the post, everytime I submit the form the post is automatically scheduled.

Whats going on and what can I do to get it working normal again? Its super annoying.

Thanks!

-- UPDATE --

As requested te code that creates the post:

### INSERT POST

```
        $new_post = array(
                'comment_status' => 'open',
                'ping_status' => 'open',
                'post_title' => $productName,
                'post_content' => $productDesc,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_author' => $currentUser,
                'post_type' => 'products',
                'post_category' => array(0)
                );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly is happening and code implementing it. _Something_ had changed for behavior to change.

Comment: Ok, I've updated it with the code I use to create the post.

Comment: Are you sure that `date()` there produces what you expect it to? PHP's date functions are highly unreliable in WP environment since it resets time zone and stuff.

Comment: @rarst you know what, that very well could be the issue. I will look into that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JonFurry did you find that this was indeed the issue?